# convert type 'uint' to 'int' in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to assign an int to an hex number.
const int a = 0xFFFFFFF0;
I got an error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'uint'. An explicit conversion exsist (are you missing a cast?)
Does someone know how to fix it?
tnx

Answer (score 16):

```
    const int a = unchecked((int)0xFFFFFFF0);
```

or simpler:

```
    const int a = -16;
```

Comment: Using `unchecked` is certainly the best approach. This case is one of the reasons why that keyword was introduced to C# in the first place...

Comment: @paja, well... *normally* it has more to do with runtime behaviour of overflows, not tricking the compiler. But it works, at least.

Comment: @Paja except interestingly the *default* for C# is unchecked; so the fact that we have to use the unchecked operator to move from unchecked to unchecked is... interesting ;p

Comment: @Mark Gravell: That is true for non-constant expressions, but not for [constant expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691349(v=vs.71).aspx), which is the case here.

Comment: @Paja - I see it: "For constant expressions (expressions that can be fully evaluated at compile-time), the default overflow checking context is always checked. Unless a constant expression is explicitly placed in an unchecked context, overflows that occur during the compile-time evaluation of the expression always cause compile-time errors." interesting. Hadn't noticed that line before.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
const uint a = 0xFFFFFFF0
```

;-)

Background: `0xFFFFFFF0` is too big to fit into an `int`, which goes from − 2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647, where as `uint` goes from 0 to 4,294,967,295, which is just above `0xFFFFFFF0` (= 4,294,967,280).

Comment: hi, I cant define it as an uint because i need int...                                                               const int a = (int)(uint)0xFFFFFFF0;  doesnt help (and it is like  const int a = (int)0xFFFFFFF0;) now I get an error: constant value '4294967280' cannot be converted to 'int' (use unchecked syntaxto override)

Comment: @jerry: See my updated answer. The value you are trying to store is too big for an `int`, so you can't store it in one.

Answer (score 1):

Int32.MaxValue is 0x7FFFFFFF . I guess c# is trying to convert the value you're trying to assing to a uint (which can accomodate it) before assigning it

Answer (score 0):

store the 0xFFFFFFF0 variable into an uint, because it's too big to fit inside an int

Comment: Sure you can... it is just -16, but it fits fine

Comment: @Marc: You can store the same bits, but it is a different meaning -16 != 4,294,967,280

Comment: @Daniel if we are talking about `int` using C# terms, then -16 === 4,294,967,280 - sort-of ;p

Comment: @Marc: I know that, that's what I meant by saying "you can store the same bits". It depends on what he wants to do, if he needs the value, he can't just use -16... If he needs the bits, you solution is the way to go, otherwise, it is NOT.

Answer (score 0):

there is another way to convert without using the *unchecked* keyword:

```
uint ui = 0xFFFFFFFF;

int ii = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(ui),0);// this is -1
```